# Dark theme for Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

I wanted to know how to add a nice dark theme to my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. I have tried looking up some sites, but to no use. I looked at https://askubuntu.com/questions/800730/dark-gtk-theme-for-ubuntu-16-04-unity, but I couldn't find the repositories there. I looked at `openSUSE` site but couldn't find how to activate the theme that I've installed. I'm new at Ubuntu. Can anyone please give a detailed answer on which themes are the best, the installation and the activation steps?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to install themes, you'll need an app called `unity-tweak-tool`

Open the terminal by using the `CTRL + ALT + T` shortcuts, and type `sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool` and enter your password to continue. To launch the app, type `unity-tweak-tool`. If you click the [themes icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBnE9.png), you will see all the [available themes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYoiE.png) on your desktop.

> ...the installation and the activation steps?

[Here](https://itsfoss.com/install-themes-ubuntu/) is a nice tutorial to install themes on your ubuntu by itsfoss

> Can anyone please give a detailed answer on which themes are the best...

[Arc dark theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rywBM.png) by noobslab is a great, dark theme. I just installed it and i loved! Its "mixed" with the default look of ubuntu 16.04 LTS. [Here is another picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouGI8.png). It also has its own icon theme! (which im not using)

The downloads, and the installation steps can be found on [Noobslab page](https://www.noobslab.com/2017/01/arc-theme-light-dark-versions-and-arc.html)